# Need a regular expression I cannot find

Tags: php, regex, validation

What would be regular expression for this : `10/04/2012 3:02 AM` in php

I'm searching all day and can't find any one.
I'm new to regular expressions.

Comment: What text have you got and what do you want to convert it to

Comment: What is your goal? Do you want to find timestamps in larger texts? Or you want to validate whether a given string is a date? Which date formats do you need to allow? Is this mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy (does it matter)? Are leading zeroes allowed/required?

Comment: i want to check it's format

i want it to be nn/nn/nnnn n:nn LL


n - number and L - Uppercase letter

Comment: Why do you need that check? Read about [PHP's DateTime](http://php.net/datetime), maybe you be better of using that…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\d` means digit. If you only want to check the general format, then use

```
\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M
```

In PHP, to find a timestamp in the string `$subject`:

```
if (preg_match('%\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M%', $subject, $regs)) {
    $result = $regs[0];
}
```

If you need to check whether the entire string fits this format, use

```
if (preg_match('%^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4} \d{1,2}:\d{2} [AP]M$%', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
}
```

instead (and then use a date library to check the date for validity).

Comment: This is a good answer. You can use a regex to check the baseline format, then extract the individual bits and convert them to integers for range checks (ie, date validation).